# Water safety during touring?

Tags: safety, touring, hydration

*[This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/food-during-touring) raised a new sub-problem of which I was not at all aware of.*

I carry a heater to boil the water before I drink it but I am unsure whether it removes all dirt from water. Please, note the water may contain some mineralization (noted in the earlier question). There are different types of tools to test for different mineralization such as arsenic but probably many others. Please, teach/show how to handle water during touring.

**Helper questions**

2. How do you maintain your water?
3. How to operate with water bags?
4. How to maintain water-containers?

**Related questions**

1. Water tests during travelling? - a general question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/786/water-tests-during-travelling).
2. How do you carry the water suitable for touring? Answered [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/carrying-water-during-touring).

Comment: @hhh - I'd like to answer the part of this question about carrying water, but I don't know anything about purifying or testing water. If you open a separate question on carrying water, I can answer that.

Comment: @Neil Fein: please http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/carrying-water-during-touring

Comment: @wdypdx22: please, teach how you do it then. Stick to mistakes if you find such and *show a better way*. How can you carry water during touring? How do you organize refills/fills/emptying/hygieny/safety? Do you plan them beforehand?

Comment: @hhh - You're asking everything from testing arsenic/pollution levels to cleaning water bottles. Honestly, I don't think about different types of tools to test for different mineralization.

Comment: @Jeff - Why was the touring tag removed? (I tried restoring it but the system won't let me.)

Comment: @neil totally unrelated, see http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms and start typing that tag..

Comment: @Jeff - Left you a message in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/bicycles).

Comment: @Jeff: @Neil: I thin it would be better to move this kind of broad questions to travel.SE.com now because it is open and leave just clearly bicycle-related-questions to bicycles.SE.com. Otherwise, SE sites are spam soon. Although I tried to ask the question as bicycle-related, answers are less targeted to bicycles -- more about water safety.

Comment: ...or to make many small questions about the helper questions, now the current form is a bit too broad.

Comment: @hhh - Nice edit! No reason you can't have a water handling question on *both* sites. (If you want to discuss this more, it would make more sense start a thread in meta or in chat.)

Comment: @Neil Fein: the water-safety and management/operation during touring are two different topics altogether. They are not the same questions at all. I am trying to attract here questions that are more about management and operation, rather than scientific water-safety. Is there some label for this kind of practical questions?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than boiling water get one of these filters from [katadyn](http://www.katadyn.com/caen/)  or [MSR](http://cascadedesigns.com/msr/water-treatment-and-hydration/category)

[image]

It won't remove all chemical poisons - but neither will boiling - it can remove some depending on how soluble they are. See [Water filter use](http://equipped.org/watrfood.htm#WaterFilters)

And unless you are drinking from chemical waste spills for weeks on end I wouldn't worry, if one area is high in arsenic the next won't be !

Comment: @mgb: the question is a bit broader than "use a filter" answers.

Comment: Your link also mentions a reverse osmosis unit which does solve much of the mineralisation problem.

Comment: reverse osmosis is lot more weight/cost/effort - unless you only salt water, or your only water source is a 3rd world sewer it's a bit over the top!

Comment: The equipped.org link contains more info about iodine, filters, water sources etc. But if you have suspect tap water or a stream away from civilisation a pump filter is perfect

Comment: @mgb: the second link is broken

Comment: @Martin Beckett: is this answer more appropriate to [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/786/water-tests-during-travelling) or here? I feel this answer is too general for bicycles.SE but great for travel.SE, hence opened a question there to migrate such answers. I moved my answer and I hope to attract here answers targeting the clearly bicycle-related questions above.